# IOS Alert Box Is Behind Screen

Tags: ios, uialertview

IOS 6.0.1 on multiple devices, There is a state where the alert box is actually behind the screen / current window.  We see the alert box appear and then "go away".  TextField focus does not work until the app is backgrounded / foregrounded and then the alert box (modal) appears and is OKed.  Then TextField focus works fine, etc.

I thought that this was impossible to do with IOS?  I will be working on a work around, but just wanted to ask this question.

Comment: could you show the code that brings up the alert box?

Comment: Well, it is pretty involved.  I am going to try a few things tonight and get back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had to do with an email screen and the result of the email.  I was doing an alert on the main thread, but if the timing was correct, the alert would come up and then the main view controller would go over it.  I have seen this before, but the alert box would come back on top.  Here it did not.  If I would put the app to the background and then foreground it, the alert would be on top.

I changed the timing a bit, delaying the alert box a bit more, and then it would come up on top.

Strange...